# A simple geometric method for finding the square roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider the following method for finding the $2$ square roots of a complex number:

- Draw the number on an $XY$ plane, as a vector starting from $(0,0)$
- Let $L$ denote the length of that vector
- Let $A$ denote the angle between that vector and the positive side of the $X$ axis
- The square roots are:

  - A vector starting from $(0,0)$, with length $\sqrt[2]{L}$ and angle $\frac{1}{2}A$
  - A vector starting from $(0,0)$, stretching to the same length in the opposite direction

Is this method generally correct for any given complex number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct.  If you write the complex number in polar form, $z=L \exp(iA)$ you are computing $\sqrt L \exp (i\frac A 2)$ and $\sqrt L \exp (i(\frac A 2+ \pi ))$ which are just what you want.

Comment: $exp(k)$ being $e^k$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I find it a little easier to read this way as the exponent is in a larger font.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)